# cisco SNMPV3 only connect to a remote host

Tags: snmp, cisco

here is the SNMPv3 i am using

snmp-server group GROUP1 v3 Priv match prefix  read v1default write v1default
snmp-server user USER1 group1 v3 auth sha PASSWORD109 priv aes 128 Password234

i have changed the priv and sha passwords and the group and user names my question is how do i target so that only a specific host can access the SNMPV3 for example host = 192.168.1.200

Answer (score 0):

You can set an ACL to the group on Cisco IOS:

```
switch(config)#snmp-server group fish v3 auth access ? 
<1-99>  Std IP accesslist allowing access with this group
WORD    Access-list name
ipv6    Specify IPv6 Named Access-List
```

Of course you'd need to have an ACL prepared in the fist place like:

```
access-list 1 permit 192.168.1.200
```

and then apply this to the group with:

```
snmp-server group GROUP1 v3 auth access 1
```